# Gitlab SSH https different content

Tags: git, gitlab, pull

In `d/POUB`: `git pull` by ssh

```
seeqlee@LAPTOP-N74Q07QC MINGW64 /d/POUB/genealogy (master)
 $ git remote --v
 origin  git@gitlab.com:moueza/genealogy.git (fetch)
 origin  git@gitlab.com:moueza/genealogy.git (push)

 seeqlee@LAPTOP-N74Q07QC MINGW64 /d/POUB/genealogy (master)
 $ ls
 ADC_MOUEZA300919.pdf                          moueza_janvrillette.PNG
 ADC_MOUEZA300919_fromAdobeReader.txt          README.md
 ADC_MOUEZA300919_fromGoogleDriveDocument.txt

 seeqlee@LAPTOP-N74Q07QC MINGW64 /d/POUB/genealogy (master)
 $ ls
 ADC_MOUEZA300919.pdf                          moueza_janvrillette.PNG
 ADC_MOUEZA300919_fromAdobeReader.txt          README.md
 ADC_MOUEZA300919_fromGoogleDriveDocument.txt

 seeqlee@LAPTOP-N74Q07QC MINGW64 /d/POUB/genealogy (master)
 $ git remote --v
 origin  git@gitlab.com:moueza/genealogy.git (fetch)
 origin  git@gitlab.com:moueza/genealogy.git (push)

 seeqlee@LAPTOP-N74Q07QC MINGW64 /d/POUB/genealogy (master)
 $ git pull
 Already up to date.

seeqlee@LAPTOP-N74Q07QC MINGW64 /d/POUB/genealogy (master)
$ ls
ADC_MOUEZA300919.pdf                          moueza_janvrillette.PNG
ADC_MOUEZA300919_fromAdobeReader.txt          README.md
ADC_MOUEZA300919_fromGoogleDriveDocument.txt
```

In `d/git`: `git pull` by https for the same Gitlab repo (https://gitlab.com/moueza/genealogy) :

```
seeqlee@LAPTOP-N74Q07QC MINGW64 /d/git/genealogy (master)
$ git remote --v
origin  https://gitlab.com/moueza/genealogy.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/moueza/genealogy.git (push)

seeqlee@LAPTOP-N74Q07QC MINGW64 /d/git/genealogy (master)
$ ls
ADC_MOUEZA300919.pdf
ADC_MOUEZA300919_fromAdobeReader.txt
ADC_MOUEZA300919_fromGoogleDriveDocument.txt
moueza_janvrillette.PNG
pom.xml
README.md
src/
target/
TraitementDeLaGrammaireFichierText.java
```

As you can see, the content is not the same in local working directory repository pulled by SSH vs by HTTPS.
Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) is not the same as a [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone): if they are additional untracked files in an existing local repository (where you pull), said files won't be impacted and will remain in place.

Do a `git status` to check if said untracked files exist.

Try and clone your repository with an HTTPS URL in a new empty local folder: its content should be the same this time.

Comment: As you can see the sequence, I do not use pull at the same place as clone. I've  just forgotten git status to reveal  /d/git/genealogy had uncommited files. Thank you !

Comment: @moueza yes, uncommitted files, that I mentioned in my answer.